# Anonymous methods - 3 different ways - async

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, methods, anonymous-function, blazor

Was unsure what to write in the title, they might not all be anonymous methods, but here goes:

Say we have this async function:

```
public async Task Delete(){  
  //something
}
```

I'm using Blazor server-side and I'm curious about the following four ways of calling a function. Lets say they are inside a div tag.

1. `onclick="@Delete"`
2. `onclick="@(() => Delete(id))"`
3. `onclick="@(async () => await Delete(id))"`
4. `onclick="@(e => Delete(person.Id))`

I'm not sure if 1 is new to Blazor or not, but does it understand that the method is async or not?

2 and 3 would be used if it was needed to pass in a parameter, but I've never used the async-part before, only seen in older posts. Is it still needed to say `"async () =>"` ?

Comment: To 3: calling something with `await` assumes your method is `async`. So yes, you need one when using the other.

Comment: Good catch. Made the psudo code a little too quick

Answer (score 10):

In the early versions of Blazor you were required to use option 3 because `async` functions weren't supported. If you missed the `await` there was no way for Blazor to know the method had finished so you needed to manually call `StateHasChanged` so the component could be re-rendered if required.

However, now Blazor does support async methods so you can stick with option 1, with the caveat that you need the method to return `Task` and not `void`.

So you need something like this:

```
public async Task Delete(){  
  //something
}
```

And in Blazor:

```
onclick="@Delete"
```

Comment: Thanks. (oof, comments do not like newlines) When needing to send in parameters, which of the versions would you suggest 2/3 or 4?
Regarding 4, does it require "async" before "e" or "await" before the "Delete" or?

Feels like I'm mixing up different concepts here. If you got time I'd love to hear/get confirmation what the consept/context of 1, 2/3 and 4 is. 

My understanding of it:
1: ??
2: non-async anonymous method
3: async anonymous method
4: lambda expression - better/worse/why?

Comment: For parameters, just pass them in like you would any method `@Delete(value1, value2)`

Comment: That doesn't work for me actually. I have this:
 @{ string textParam= "Texty";}
 <button type="button" @onclick="ChangeLang(textParam)">Click</button>

The method looks like this: "private async Task ChangeLang(string incParam)"

I'm getting the compiler error: "Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'"

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-parameters) and the `EventCallback` delegate. Sorry, I'm not near a Blazor compatible IDE right now to check

Comment: @Track, I encountered this issue with parameters, too. It appears that options 2 and 3 (for async) are the way to go in this case. No skin off your back, hopefully.