# Avoid event delegate recreation for async methods

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app with many buttons rendered in a for-loop.:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < _navItems.Count; i++)
{
  var localI = i;
  <div class="col-3 mb-2">
     <button @onclick="async () => await SetCurrentAsync(localI)" class="btn btn-sm">
       @(i + 1)
     </button>
  </div>
}
```

However, this approach is not recommended by Microsoft Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-6.0#avoid-recreating-delegates-for-many-repeated-elements-or-components) because the delegates specified in `@onclick` are recreated each time the component is rendered:

> Blazor's recreation of lambda expression delegates for elements or components in a loop can lead to poor performance.

The solution provided in the docs thereafter(and also in the [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17886) is to create a `Button` type with an `Action` property that holds the delegate:

```
@foreach (var button in _buttons)
{
  <div class="col-3 mb-2">
   <button @key="button.Id" @onclick="button.Action" class="btn btn-sm">
    @(i + 1)
   </button>
  </div>
}

@code {
   
     List<Button> _buttons = new();
     List<NavItem> _items;

     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
        _items = await GetItemsFromDb();
        for(int i = 0; i < _items.Count; i++)
        {
            var localI = i;
            _buttons.Add(new Button 
            { 
               Id = item.Id, 
               Action = () => SetCurrent(localI);  
            });
        }
     }

    class Button 
    {
         public int Id { get; set; }
         
         public Action Action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, the `@onclick` references `Button.Action` and solves the delegate recreation problem.

It is all fun and games until `SetCurrent` is not async.
`Action` will have to be changed to `Func<Task>`  and buttons will have to be added using an async lambda expression:

```
_buttons.Add(new Button 
{ 
  Id = item.Id, 
  Action = async () => await SetCurrentAsync(localI);  
});
```

And I still have to do:

```
@onclick="async() => await button.Action"
```

which would again recreate the delegates.
How exactly can I do this for async methods?

Comment: I don't know much Blazor but why would you need to do `async() => await button.Action`? You already do this when assigning that `Action`. That is - why not just do `button.Action`?

Comment: I'd even say there is no reason to change anything. `Action = () => SetCurrentAsync(localI)`, no need to await anything here, your `Action` is `Func<Task>` and that already returns `Task`. And same with click handler, it supports handlers which return task, so just do `onclick="button.Action"

Comment: @Evk see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497072/execute-async-method-on-button-click-in-blazor), it's already a known pattern

Comment: @Evk Thanks. I wasn't completely sure if the on click handler would internally await the method and I didn't want to end up not awaiting the task. But it appears that it does, in fact, internally await and doesn't need an additional one.

Comment: @gunr2171 It seems like the await is not required anymore in newer versions of Blazor. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60488286/11455105).

Comment: That's actually really good to know. This was something driving me crazy as well.

Comment: It went away a long time ago.  It seriously irks me every time I still see in MS Docs.  You see it in MS Docs, it must be the right way!

Comment: Even if click was not internally awaited - your approach wouldn't change anything. You just wrap one task inside another task, which is not (internally) awaited, and the result is the same (exceptions will not propagate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, doing something like this

```
@onclick="async () => await SetCurrentAsync(localI)"
```

is unnecessary.  You're wrapping a Task within a Task.

```
@onclick="()=> SetCurrentAsync(localI)"
```

works exactly the same.  The Blazor Component internal event handler (for button clicks,...) wraps whatever action you pass in a Task.  At it's simplest it looks like this:

```
var task = InvokeAsync(EventMethod);
StateHasChanged();
if (!task.IsCompleted)
{
    await task;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

You should always use `Func<Task>` to handle both `sync Task` and `Task`.  Using an `Action` with an async method is a NoNo - It returns a `void` to the Blazor Component event handler.

See the code page below for a working demo.  There are three buttons that use the pattern

1. First calls a yielding Task method with async Task.
2. Second calls a simple Task method.
3. Uses an `Action` with `async void` and demonstrates the UI update problem .

The key is that the first two both return a `Task` to the Blazor Component event handler so it can handle component rendering correctly.

```
@page "/"
<h3>Button Actions</h3>

@foreach (var item in _buttonActions)
{
    <div class="m-2">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="item.Action">@item.Title</button>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @message
</div>

@code {
    private List<ButtonAction> _buttonActions = new List<ButtonAction>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        {
            var item = new ButtonAction() { Title = "Task" };
            item.Action = () => GetValue(item);
            _buttonActions.Add(item);
        }
        {
            var item = new ButtonAction() { Title = "Async Task" };
            item.Action = () => GetValueAsync(item);
            _buttonActions.Add(item);
        }
        {
            var item = new ButtonAction() { Title = "Async Void Task" };
            item.MyAction = () => GetValueVoidAsync(item);
            _buttonActions.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private string message;

    public Task GetValue(ButtonAction item)
    {
        message = $"Value: {item.Id}";
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task GetValueAsync(ButtonAction item)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        message = $"Value: {item.Id}";
    }

    public async void GetValueVoidAsync(ButtonAction item)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        message = $"Value: {item.Id}";
    }

    public class ButtonAction
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public Func<Task> Action { get; set; }
        public Action MyAction { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On performance, I think it really depends on "How many?".  I don't use the pattern for edit lists were I may have 25 edit and view buttons.  I've never noticed a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was concerned about performance because in my case, sometimes you could end up with little more than a hundred buttons. (It's a question navigator for a quiz)