# Proper way to call async method from component property

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

When consuming a component in another razor component, there is usually a need to call async methods triggered by an EventCallback property, `onClick` for instance. Is there any particular way to call it to assure asynchronicity?

Let's assume the following example:

```
@* CASE 1*@
<MyButton OnClick=DoSomething>Click Me</MyButton>

@* CASE 2*@
<MyButton OnClick=@(async () => await DoSomething())>Click Me</MyButton>

@code {
    private async Task DoSomething(){ ... }
}
```

After compiling, is there any distinction between using a delegate or calling the function directly? Should we prefer one or the other?

This question doesn't derive from an error or code running improperly but only from the fact that I get no feedback from Visual Studio and probably for a good reason but I would like to know if I'm writing improper code either way.

Choice Remark: Hard to pick a single answer for all provide valid points to the discussion, further reading is encouraged. It seems the confusion stems from a misunderstanding of the delegate's role in the call stack, in that way I think that Shaun's answer shows the most succinct and explicit example of that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute async method on button click in blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497072/execute-async-method-on-button-click-in-blazor)

Comment: @kltft Thanks for sharing, I've missed it. It's similar but in the end looks like there are people supporting both sides and the uncertainty still remains. I guess we should use the most appropriate case for the occasion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific case, the first is better.

This code block is wrapping a Task within a Task.  It wasteful on resources: each Task is a state machine object.

```cs
OnClick=@(async () => await DoSomething())>
```

However, what actually happens depends on `MyButton`.

Here's a demo version.  I've added two button event handlers, with comments on how each executes.

```cs
<button @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes @onclick=this.OnButtonClickAsync></button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public Dictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    private async Task OnButtonClickAsync(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // you are awaiting the delegate in the parent component
        // if it yields you'll await it's completion
        await this.OnClick.InvokeAsync(e);
        // Code here will only execute after the parent delegate has completed, awaits and all
        // any exceptions will bubble up to here 
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // This is a Fire and Forget call
        this.OnClick.InvokeAsync(e);
        // code here will execute as soon as the parent delegate yields
        // exceptions won't bubble up to here
    }
}
```

More generally, it's a matter of personal preference.

I like clean markup, so I code like this.

```cs
<button disabled="@buttonCss"></button>

@code {
    private bool _isDisabled;
    private string buttonCss => _isDisabled ? "btn btn-danger" : "btn btn-success";
}
```

Others like succinct [inline] code.

```cs
<button disabled="@(_isDisabled ? "btn btn-danger": "btn btn-success")"></button>

@code {
    private bool _isDisabled;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lambda expressions are fully supported and in fact, in some cases they may be required.  Consider you are doing a `@foreach(item in items)` to pass the item to the function you'd likely need to use a lambda expression:

`@(async () => await DoSomething(item))`

Here is Microsoft documentation supporting lambas:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Indeed, I've used both cases in similar scenarios but I'm still not sure if using a Lambda is required to ensure the method runs async, even when it doesn't need arguments passed in.

Comment: @Hugo check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#focus-an-element). No lambda used. There are plenty other examples in Blazor documentation with the same approach.

Comment: This code is wasteful.  It wraps a Task within a Task.  just calling `DoSomething(item)` achieves the same result.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis you will get error if you try to do that: cannot convert Task to EventCallback.  Its basically if you are in foreach and need to pass "current" item you're gonna get in this situation.

Comment: Apologies, I was too succinct.   What I meant was `OnClick="() => DoSomething(item)"`.  You don't need the extra Task wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any particular way to call it to assure asynchronicity?

That is taken care of by the EventCallback. The OnClick accepts both `void` and `Task` methods and will await a Task.

As for how to the use it, there is a third case. I have renumbered them:

```
@* CASE 1*@
<MyButton OnClick="DoSomething">Click Me</MyButton>
```

This is the cleanest and most efficient. It passes a delegate directly to the generated code.

```
@* CASE 2*@
<MyButton OnClick="() => DoSomething()">Click Me</MyButton>
```

This adds a lambda (method) and then passes a delegate reference to that lambda. Adding a little overhead.
You only need this pattern when there is a parameter:

```
@* CASE 2b*@
@* item is usually something from a surrounding @foreach *@
<MyButton OnClick="(item) => DoSomething(item)">Click Me</MyButton>
```

```
@* CASE 3*@
<MyButton OnClick="(async () => await DoSomething())">Click Me</MyButton>
```

This adds an async state machine on top of the lambda. More unnecessary overhead. You can look up "eliding async and await" for the details.

Conclusion: use Case 1 or Case 2b.
That is valid advice for both `void` and `Task` returning methods.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet taken straight out of [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

> In the following example, `UpdateHeading`:
>
> - Is called asynchronously when the button is selected.
> - Waits two seconds before updating the heading.
>
> `Pages/EventHandlerExample2.razor`:

```
@page "/event-handler-example-2"

<h1>@currentHeading</h1>

<p>
    <label>
        New title
        <input @bind="newHeading" />
    </label>
    <button @onclick="UpdateHeading">
        Update heading
    </button>
</p>

@code {
    private string currentHeading = "Initial heading";
    private string? newHeading;

    private async Task UpdateHeading()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);

        currentHeading = $"{newHeading}!!!";
    }
}
```

As you can see lambda is not used (`@onclick="UpdateHeading"`) but still it is mentioned that `UpdateHeading` **will be called asynchronously**.

Also when passing parameters, wrapping in async await is not required. The following will work correctly:

```
@page "/event-handler-example-2"

<h1>@currentHeading</h1>

<p>
    <label>
        New title
        <input @bind="newHeading" />
    </label>
    <button @onclick="() => UpdateHeading(2000)">
        Update heading
    </button>
</p>

@code {
    private string currentHeading = "Initial heading";
    private string? newHeading;

    private async Task UpdateHeading(int delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);

        currentHeading = $"{newHeading}!!!";
    }
}
```

A lambda with async/await would be useful if instead of declaring `UpdateHeading`, you wanted to use anonymous method:

```
@page "/event-handler-example-2"

<h1>@currentHeading</h1>

<p>
    <label>
        New title
        <input @bind="newHeading" />
    </label>
    <button @onclick="@(async () => { await Task.Delay(2000); currentHeading = $"{newHeading}!!!"; })">
        Update heading
    </button>
</p>

@code {
    private string currentHeading = "Initial heading";
    private string? newHeading;
}
```