# Why can an AsyncEventHandler method return void or Task?

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor has a callback AsyncEventHandler struct that is used for declaring events in a component. [Here’s a useful discussion about how to get called by the event.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771090/proper-way-to-call-async-method-from-component-property)

I’ve found that the method assigned to an AsyncEventHandler can return void or Task. How can it return void when it’s declared to return Task. Does the system view a return of void being a Task that has completed?

And I’m talking here of a method that returns void, not “async void”. So a truly synchronous method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can it return void when it’s declared to return Task.

Inside the EventCallback the method is stored in `internal readonly MulticastDelegate? Delegate;`

A `MulticastDelegate` is for methods what an `object` reference is for class objects, it accepts *all* method signatures and return types.

And later it is executed with type matching patterns:

```
   internal static Task InvokeAsync<T>(MulticastDelegate? @delegate, T arg)
   {
       switch (@delegate)
       {      
           case Action action:
               action.Invoke();           // void
               return Task.CompletedTask;
      
           case Func<Task> func:
               return func.Invoke();      // Task

           // more branches
       }
   }
```

There are more branches, mostly for dealing with the optional `T` parameter. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/EventCallbackWorkItem.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Incoming UI events are handled through the Renderer.

If the component implements `IHandleEvent`:, the Renderer wraps the event in an `EventCallbackWorkItem` and schedules `IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync`.  If it doesn't it schedules the component's event handler directly.

Here's the UI event handler for `ComponentBase`.

```
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        // After each event, we synchronously re-render (unless !ShouldRender())
        // This just saves the developer the trouble of putting "StateHasChanged();"
        // at the end of every event callback.
        StateHasChanged();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Here's `EventCallbackWorkItem.InvokeAsync`.  Note the handling of different `delegate` types.  A `void` returning method is handled as a `Action`.  It returns a `Task.CompletedTask` regardless of whether the action yields or not.

```cs
    internal static Task InvokeAsync<T>(MulticastDelegate? @delegate, T arg)
    {
        switch (@delegate)
        {
            case null:
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            case Action action:
                action.Invoke();
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            case Action<T> actionEventArgs:
                actionEventArgs.Invoke(arg);
                return Task.CompletedTask;

            case Func<Task> func:
                return func.Invoke();

            case Func<T, Task> funcEventArgs:
                return funcEventArgs.Invoke(arg);

                //.....
```

A couple of further points:

1. Ultimately the "event" get's posted to the Synchronisation Context as either a synchronous code block or a block of code using an Async State Machine.
2. The application creates a cached `Task.CompletedTask so it's cheap to return.

### Appendix to answer the comment.

Your *Async* method can return what it likes, including a void.

It's up to the caller to decide what it likes, and doesn't like.

In the code above, `InvokeAsync` handles various method patterns.

Consider this code:

```cs
        Task task1 = Task.Yield();
        Task task2 = Task.Delay(100);
```

The `Yield` version errors because it returns is a `YieldAwaitable`.  If you check the `Delay` signature you'll see *(awaitable) Task*.

As soon as you want to `await` something, it needs to implement the *Awaitable* pattern and return an *Awaiter*.  You can await `Yield`, `Delay` and any `Task` returning method because the objects they return implement a `GetAwaiter()`.

Here's a slightly crazy demonstrator:

Add this static method to `Int32`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this Int32 milliseconds)
    {
        return Task.Delay(milliseconds).GetAwaiter();
    }
}
```

And now you can do this:

```cs
   await 500;
```

Ultimately code gets posted onto threads where there's no concept of await or a return value.  In async behaviour the code block running on the thread holds a reference to an *awaiter/awaitable* object (normally a `Task`).  When it completes it sets the *awaiter* status, the *awaiter* result and schedules any continuations registered on the *awaiter*.

Comment: First off thanks. Second, correct me if I'm wrong, but a return of void cannot be used when a return of Task is expected. It works here because of the switch(@delegate) that calls the void method, then returns Task.CompletedTask. Is that correct? TIA

Comment: Before I answer, How much do you know about async/await and the AsyncStateMachine?

Comment: Every time I think I can say I understand async/await well, something like this comes up that makes me think I don't know it at all. I've read, and think I follow, the main blogs on it by the Stephens (Cleary & Toub). So lets say a moderate level of understanding with some misconceptions.

Comment: I know that *mere mortal* feeling!  I'm currently trying to put together a series of documents on the subject. see https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.AsyncAwait/.  It's a work in progress.  Anyway see my modified answer.

Comment: I finally moved up a level when I sat down and coded my own state machine, Yield, Delay and awaitable/awaiter.  It was an interesting experience in going round in circles.

Comment: thanks - for the additional content here and the link.